# Does the CFBundleURLIconFile key have any purpose in iOS?

Tags: ios, icons, info.plist, custom-scheme-url

In an app's Info.plist the developer has the opportunity to declare custom URL schemes supported by the app. The developer may also associate each scheme with an Apple Icon Image (icns) file in the bundle that will serve as an icon.

**I have never seen these URL icons used anywhere, and I can't imagine how they even would be used. Is there any purpose to setting them?**

Answer (score 1):

That is not an iOS thing, but is instead intended for OS X/macOS.

[You can read some about it here on the macOS Human Interface Guidelines page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Designing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH87-SW1).